# Paging after specific number

Tags: php, mysql

I show 21 news in table with this sql:

```
 WHERE cat_id = $id  ORDER BY added_date DESC LIMIT 0, 21;
```

I want to show news after 21 with paging but I'm confusing about SQL:

```
WHERE cat_id = $id  ORDER BY added_date DESC LIMIT $start, $pergape;
```

This SQL show all news. How can I show news after 21 in second sql?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not have to add comments for this, we can see that you have edited the question.

Comment: Note that it's often less confusing to use the PostgreSQL style `LIMIT  $perpage OFFSET $start` which is also supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Set `$start` equal to `$page_size * $page_number`. Your query would look something like:

```
$page_size = 21;
$page_number = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 0;

$start = $page_size * $page_number;

$query = ' ... WHERE cat_id = $id  ORDER BY added_date DESC LIMIT $start, $page_size;'
```

Comment: in my paging: $perpage = 21; if ($page) $start = ($page - 1) * $perpage;

Comment: @TheNone: Yes, that makes more sense for most people. I'm used to 0-indexed lists.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL looks correct apart from the obvious omission of the `SELECT ... FROM ...` which I assume you have in your code.

I'm not sure if this explains the results you get but you have misspelled `$perpage` in your query:

```
WHERE cat_id = $id  ORDER BY added_date DESC LIMIT $start, $pergape;
                                                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Try printing the SQL after the values of the PHP variables have been substituted in and the error will most likely become obvious. If it's correct should look something like this:

```
WHERE cat_id = 134  ORDER BY added_date DESC LIMIT 21, 21;
```